# convert fmx project to vcl Delphi XE10

Tags: delphi, firebase

I try to use firebase in my project , and I found an example about firebase her [Firebase4Delphi](https://github.com/spinettaro/Firebase4Delphi) but they are using FMX instead of VCL,
How can I using it in VCL project not in FMX ?

the main problem is here, I can't find `TListViewItem` in VCL application library:

```
procedure TMainForm.OnNewMessage(AChatMsg: TChatMessage);
var
  Item: TListViewItem;
begin
  try
    ListView1.BeginUpdate;
    try
      Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
      Item.Text := AChatMsg.Msg;
      Item.Detail := AChatMsg.Username;
    finally
      ListView1.EndUpdate;
    end;

  finally
    AChatMsg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. You cannot change the entire meaning of your question after it has received answers. Such a change invalidates those answers, wasting the time of those who wrote them and possibly negatively impacting their reputation due to downvotes they receive on those now invalid answers. If you now have a different issue, write a new question and ask about it there. This question is about an issue with `TListViewItem`, and the answer below addresses that issue.

Comment: Indeed, you appeared to be using some third-party unit as well, which I happened to find on Google. The unit is apparently in Alpha. Did you consider that maybe that unit is broken, and you should consult the vendor?

Comment: I suggest you attempt to understand what you are doing before trying to continue. You won't succeed with your current approach.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to convert a FMX project automatically to a VCL project. In a VCL project the item of a ListView is from type TListItem. Try this:

```
procedure TMainForm.OnNewMessage(AChatMsg: TChatMessage);
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  try
    Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
    Item.Caption := AChatMsg.Msg;
  finally
    AChatMsg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I try it , But nothing show in a ListView1 ! are you try take a look on Firebase4Delphi example ??

Comment: @junior.programmer Your problem is elsewhere, the above code should work just fine, assuming `OnNewMessage` is in fact called, and `AChatMsg.Msg` actually has a value. Have you stepped through the code to verify this?

Comment: @JerryDodge Take a look in the code that i was updated above please.. where is the problem ?

Comment: @junior.programmer Have you used your debugger like I advised? Your code looks fine on my end.